# PyQt: How to hide everything? (whole application)

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

Is there a simple way to hide all widgets (essentially hide the whole application)? There are multiple windows and widgets not attached to any window. I'm assuming it's some sort of modifier to the `QApplication([])`.

EDIT: 
Better wording of my question thanks to @eyllanesc:

hide() method that prevents any window (or widget) from showing after using it and you also want the "show" method restore to the previous state.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Note that a widget with no parent is automatically a window (if shown), so "There are multiple windows and widgets not attached to any window" is a bit confusing statement, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to iterate over the top level widgets using `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()` and hide it:

```py
for tl in QtWidgets.QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
    tl.hide()
    # or 
    # tl.close()
```

Comment: Is there any way to just toggle a setting so I don't have to run this every time?

Comment: @jamesfdearborn mmm, I don't understand you, explain yourself better besides provide a [mre]

Comment: Sure. For a single widget I can run `widget.hide()`, and that'll hide the widget and its layout, including any widgets added to said layout after the hide command. Is there any sort of an `application.hide()` that hides all elements, even those created after the hide command?

Comment: @jamesfdearborn That's what my code does: If you hide the windows then all its children will be hidden, and the top levels are the windows. Have you tried my solution?

Comment: I have tried your solution, thanks, it is very good. But the idea is to hide all children of the application, not just the window. If I create a new widget in your application it will not be hidden. The goal of an `application.hide()` would be so that each new widget created will be hidden, and that can easily be toggled off with an `application.show()`.

Comment: @jamesfdearborn 1) Windows are not children of QApplication, 2) QApplication is not an element but a manager of the event loop. 3) From what I understand you want a "hide()" method that prevents any window (or widget) from showing after using it and you also want the "show" method restore to the previous state. , am I correct?

Comment: @jamesfdearborn You should point out the detailed behavior of what you want since if my previous comment is correct then your post is wrong.